# Retrofit and api, problems with imports

Tags: android, rest, gson, retrofit

I am using `Retrofit` and `API` in Android Studio but not sure where I am going wrong. That is my API java code. I am getting errors on the values, the form url encoded and the post

```
<package com.example.coffeeshopapp.Retrofit;
import com.example.coffeeshopapp.Model.User;
import com.example.coffeeshopapp.Model.checkUserResponse;
 import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded

public interface CoffeeShopAPI {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("checkuser.php")
Call<checkUserResponse> checkUserExists(@Field("phone")String phone);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register.php")
Call<User> registerNewUser(@Field("phone")String phone,
                           @Field("name")String name,
                           @Field("address")String address,
                           @Field("birthdate")String birthdate);
}
```

This is my code for the retrofit. Errors on retrofit and gson convertor factory.

```
package com.example.coffeeshopapp.Retrofit;

import Retrofit;

public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl)
{
    if (retrofit == null)
    {
      retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
              .baseUrl(baseUrl)
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
              .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Comment: share your error logcat plz.

Comment: Retrofit error: Cannot resolve symbol retrofit and gson converter factory

Comment: api error: cannot resolve symbol: post, formurlencoded, call and field

Comment: seems like you are not importing necessary packages make sure you have imported them you can press Alt+Enter shortcut and import necessary packages

Comment: the packages for retrofit, form url encoded, post and call dont show up am I meant to add them to dependencies in gradle file?

Comment: you need to add retrofit dependency  for it

Comment: check answer once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try following it might be helpful to you:

first of all add dependency into your build.gradle file:-

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
```

**Interface Class:-**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update-status")
Call<JsonObject> getUpdateStatus(@Field("token") String token, @Field("status") String status);
```

**API Call:-**

```
private void statusUpdateApi() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL_LOGIN).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<JsonObject> jsonObjectCall = api.getUpdateStatus(UserSession.getKeepLogin(context).getuToken(), status);
    Log.e("macro", "asd" + status);
    jsonObjectCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<JsonObject> call, @NonNull Response<JsonObject> response) {
            Log.e("123", "456" + response);
            Log.e("123", "456-->" + response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<JsonObject> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```